# Store values of multiple keys while collecting into a map stream

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, java-stream, concurrenthashmap

```
Map<String, String> x = ArrayListMultimap.create();
Map<String, Boolean> results1 = Maps.newHashMap();
Map<String, Boolean> results2 = Maps.newHashMap();
```

I have a multimap which I need to traverse and make some expensive calls. To save time, I want to do a parallel stream. The results I get can have null values which has to be stored in a map. I know how to do this in a non-parallel way, however I'm not able to do this in a parallel stream without getting into concurrency issues. I realize I need to somehow convert this into a map and collect the results, but I don't know how I can return multiple keys and values. I was thinking of having a temporary single map, but that too will have multiple keys.

```
x.keySet().paralleStream().forEach(req -> {
   try {
      Response response = getResponseForRequest(req);
      if(response.getTitles() != null) {
        boolean titleAvail = response.getTitles().stream().allMatch(Avalibilty:Status);
        x.get(req).forEach(y -> results1.put(y, titleAvail);
      }
      if(response.getDetails() != null) {
        boolean detailStatus = //perform some stream operation on getDetails
        x.get(req).forEach(y -> results2.put(y, detailStatus));
      }

   } catch(TimeoutException e) {
      x.get(req).forEach(y -> {
        results1.put(y, null);
        results2.put(y, null);
      })
   } catch(Exception e) {
    //log & do nothing
   }
});
```

Eventually what I am trying to do is call getResponseForRequest which returns me a result. And then based on the response, for each key in the multimap, store the results in 2 maps results1, and results2.

Comment: You haven't really explained what you're trying to do. Also, your code is full of compile errors.

Comment: @shmosel Updated the question (at the end).

Comment: `response.getTitle()` returns a boolean??

Comment: @shmosel Sorry. Forgot to update code. Updated now

Comment: You would have to use a `Collector`.  Do not use `put` or any other operation that modifies state in a parallel stream (or, ideally, any other stream).  You will probably have to build a heavily customized collector for this.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes thats what I want to move towards. Using a Collector. If it was a single map I was writing to, I could have just return a K,V pair with SingleEntry, but I need to collect 2 maps. That's were I'm unable to go ahead.

Comment: Build a new class that holds the two maps, and give it two methods: one  that takes in `req` and updates the maps accordingly, and one that combines two instance of this class.

Comment: Are you sure that `x` has the type `Map<String, String>`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `flatMap()`.
Declare enum: `Availability {TITLE, DETAIL}`
Then mapping:

```
x.entrySet().parallelStream()
.map(entry -> {
    // Construct mapping between y and Boolean here
    return Map<Y, EnumMap<Availability, Boolean>>;
})
.flatMap(v -> v.entrySet().stream())
.collect(v -> toMap(v.getKey(), v.getValue(), (v1, v2) -> YOUR_DEFINE_MAPPER, ConcurrentHashMap::new));
```

Hope this help